# create a relationship between non User model and AhoyMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I am using [Ahoy Email](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email) to track emails I send to my restaurants. 
However I'dd like to create a relationship like so :

- an `AhoyMessage` `belongs_to` a `Restaurant`
- a `Restaurant` `has_many` `AhoyMessages`

so that I can access, for example:

```
ahoy_message.restaurant.phone_number
==> "+33612345678"
```

I know when I look at the docs that there is an easy way to do so with the `User` model, but I can only use my `Restaurant` model and hence the example in the doc does not work for my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say it's polymorphic and you can use any model.

Try

```
class CouponMailer < ApplicationMailer
  track user: -> { Restaurant.find_by(email: message.to.first) }
end


class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, class_name: "Ahoy::Message", as: :user
end
```

So you would still use `ahoy_message.user.phone_number` but the ahoy_message.user is a polymorphic association to a restaurant object.

Comment: thank you very much @SteveTurczyn ! I actually thought about doing so but I was afraid there could be any conflict because I also have a `User` model. Are you sure there won't be any conflict ?

Comment: Not according to the docs on the Ahoy Message readme.  You could actually mix and match, so messages from one mailer the "user" would be "restaurant", and the messages from another mailer could be real users.